Mesure of a totally disconnected set of $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of real numbers equipped with the standard topology, and let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a totally disconnected subset. That is, the connected components of $A$ are trivial, meaning each connected component consists of a single point. Consequently, $A$ has an empty interior.
Assuming that $A$ is closed (so it is Lebesgue-measurable), I wonder if it necessarily follows that it is of  zero  Lebesgue measure?

No, see the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set.

Thank you very much!
